# PHP - Parse New Line Logs

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following log:

`#VERSION: 2.9
2017-02-24  10:03:39    channel_ping    1afcd2e2857045fe973e7ed036ea450c    dfe17897d80b44f6901593364fc72b55    2479884 127.0.0.1   Mozilla/5.0%20(Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_11_6)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/56.0.2924.87%20Safari/537.36    https://test.com/   TEST-User-50187 42134f99b57240d19e05f760800a9dc6`

I can read the content of this in PHP no problem which outputs:

`#VERSION: 2.9\n
2017-02-24\t10:03:39\tchannel_ping\t1afcd2e2857045fe973e7ed036ea450c\tdfe17897d80b44f6901593364fc72b55\t2479884\t127.0.0.1\tMozilla/5.0%20(Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_11_6)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/56.0.2924.87%20Safari/537.36\thttps://test.com/\tTEST-User-50187\t42134f99b57240d19e05f760800a9dc6\n
"""`

I need to be able structure this into something like so:

`array[0] = '2017-02-24';
array[1] = '10:03:39';
array[2] = 'channel_ping';`

Answer (score 1):

You can explode your output:

```
$arr = explode("\\t",$linesOf);
```

Or if $linesOf already includes the \t as a normal string:

```
$arr = explode("\t",$linesOf);
```

Before I would make a substring to get rid of the "#VERSION: 2.9\n" part...

Comment: This is close however because the first line does't end with `/t` then my first item in the array isn't clear:

`0 => """
    #VERSION: 2.9\n
    2017-02-24
    """`

Rather than:

`0 => "2017-02-24"`

I also need it to break each new line into a separate array as there could be multiple logs per file, all of which are on a  new line

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
preg_match_all("/\n(\w+?-\w+?-\w+)\t(\w+?:\w+?:\w+)\t([\w_]+)/", $strLog, $matches,  PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

That return an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
2017-02-24  10:03:39    channel_ping
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-02-24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10:03:39
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => channel_ping
        )
)
```

Finally, get values:

```
$date = $matches[1][0];
$time = $matches[2][0];
$command = $matches[3][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), with splitting on all 'space' characters  `\s`

```
$res = preg_split('/\s/i',$str);
```

Then, because there will be "empty strings" that is useless for us, we filter with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the results to remove those:

```
$res = array_filter($res, function($elem) {
                             // if it's not empty after trimming we can use it.
                             if (!empty(trim($elem))){
                                 return true;
                             }
                           return false; 
                          });
```

See it in acion:

http://ideone.com/oE49O9

```
$str = "#VERSION: 2.9\n
2017-02-24\t10:03:39\tchannel_ping\t1afcd2e2857".
"045fe973e7ed036ea450c\tdfe17897d80b44f6901593364fc72b55\t2479884\t127.0.0.1\tM".
"ozilla/5.0%20(Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_11_6)%20AppleWebKit/537.3".
"6%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/56.0.2924.87%20Safari/537.36\thttps://test".
".com/\tTEST-User-50187\t42134f99b57240d19e05f760800a9dc6\n";
$res = preg_split('/\s/i',$str);
$res = array_filter($res, function($elem) {if(!empty(trim($elem))){return true;}return false; });
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: This works well however what about a case where there are multiple lines of logs per file? I would need separated logs rather than all logs in 1 array

Comment: First do a `preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/",$content);` so you get individual arrays per line. then iterate those with the preg split given in the answer